# When to include and omit the plus-minus when applying the square root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, radicals

I'm currently studying ODE's using *Advanced Engineering Mathematics 10e (Kreyszig)* and had a question regarding solutions in square root form. Specifically, the exercise problem is:

> Find a general solution for the following ODE(s).
>
> $yy' + 36x = 0$

**My approach** is as follows:

$$
yy' + 36x = 0
$$

$$
\begin{align}
ydy & = -36xdx \\\
\frac{1}{2}y^2 & = -18x^2 + C \\\
y^2 & = -36x^2 + C \\\
y & = \pm \sqrt{-36x^2 + C} \\\
\end{align}
$$

However, I noticed that in the solution, the author omits the $\pm$. Is there a reason why it has been omitted? Further, is there a rule-of-thumb that I should keep in mind regarding omission? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, one decides whether it is + or - given a specific initial condition. You should recheck the problem and see whether an initial value was specified.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=-\sqrt{-36x^2+C}$ is also a solution to the equation (you can check this).

Either omitting the $\pm$ is an error in the book, or there's some more information about the problem you're not telling us that would allow us to conclude that $y$ is positive in this case.